# MUI datatables date custom filter

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I am using MUI Datatable to display my data. I want to create a custom filter to allow users to filter the table by MUI datepicker.

I have tried in `codesandbox` but it's not filtering:

https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-in-mui-datatables-r3dsi4

Comment: Hello, I found this [link](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/customize-filter/index.js) to be helpful. They Implement this using a number range which you can implement to a date!